# Laravel Bulk Send Mail with Notification

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I read in laravel documentation :

Once the ShouldQueue interface has been added to your notification, you may send the notification like normal. Laravel will detect the ShouldQueue interface on the class and automatically queue the delivery of the notification:

Because of in notification do automatically queue, 
if I use in my controller:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
  $users = User::all()
  Notification::send($users, new MyFirstNotification());
}
```

and in my notification:

```php
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
  return  new custome-emailTo("emails.welcome",$notifiable);
}
```

and in custom-mailTo, (it is a mailable class) :

```php
public function __construct($view2,User $user)
{
  $this->user = $user;
  $this->view = $view2;
}

public function build()
{
  $this->to($this->user->email);
  return $this->view('emails.welcome');
}
```

for me, it work and send to many users,

but my questions are:
As stated in the documentation of Laravel,

**1. Do it really do queuing for send notification?**

**2. Do I need queue in mailable laravel class for send bulk email?**

Comment: How *many* users? If you're sending to hundreds, you might be OK without queueing. If you're sending to a million, you'll almost certainly need it.

Comment: Thanks, for a few thousand, do my code will work??

Comment: Maybe. You'd want to test. It depends on a variety of variables, like the efficiency of your code and how fast your sending service processes stuff.

Comment: ok,  I would like to know more about efficiency of  my code, is it right ? and do laravel really do queuing for me?? I dont use any  queue and  jobs for my code.         do Laravel do it for me?